# Case when over partition by applied per row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

My table looks like this:

```
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
|  num_1 |  num_2 |  num_3 |level_1 | level_2 | level_3 |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
|  1111  |  3333  |  4444  |  false |  false  |  false  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
|  1111  |  3333  |  5555  |  false |  false  |  false  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
|  1111  |  6666  |  null  |  false |  false  |  false  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
|  1111  |  7777  |  8888  |  false |  true   |  false  |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|
```

So that the table looks like this:

```
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|  num_1 |  num_2 |  num_3 |level_1 | level_2 | level_3 |   result    |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|  1111  |  3333  |  4444  | false  |  false  |  false  |    3333     |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|  1111  |  3333  |  5555  | false  |  false  |  false  |    3333     |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|  1111  |  6666  |  null  | false  |  false  |  false  |    6666     |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
|  1111  |  7777  |  8888  | false  |  true   |  false  |    8888     |
|--------|--------|--------|--------|---------|---------|-------------|
```

### Edit

This is a simplified example, but here is how this table works:

- The `num_x` columns reference the ID to an element in another table, which might or might not have a certain attribute we're looking for.
- The `level_x` columns represents whether the column `num_x` with the same `x` value has that certain attribute set to `true`.
  These entries represent a hierarchy of elements which do or do not have that attribute:

```
1111 ✘ > 3333 ✘ > 4444 ✘
                 > 5555 ✘
       > 6666 ✘
       > 7777 ✓ > 8888 ✘
```

My goal is to go through the whole table, and find the lowest level for each row at which the previous level has no child level with a `true` value.
For example, for the first few rows, since all rows are children of `1111` and that `1111` has a child, `7777`, with its attribute set to `true`, all other children at the same level as `7777` would be the result of their own row, unless they do have children with their attribute set to `true` as well.
Since `7777` has its attribute set to `true`, the result of this row is its immediate child, `8888`. If it did not have a child, the row would not need a result.

Comment: Nope no idea why rows 1 and 2 has a result of `3333`. Please try explaining more carefully.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever it is `3333` meaning the level_2 because we would put it at level_3 (since level_3 is set to true) but level_2 (num_2 = `3333` is true) => we can put it at level_2. Level_1 (num_1 = '1111' is also true) but num_2 = `7777` has level_2 set to false and it blocks the ability to get 1111 as the result.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.  It may give us a clue about what you need.  Right now I have nothing.

Comment: @v0rl0n i have updated the description:
```
max(CASE WHEN ((level_1 = true and cat_1 is not null)
and ((num_2 is not null and level_2 = true) or num_2 is null) 
and ((num_3 is not null and level_3 = true) or num_3 is null)
then num_1 else null end) over (partition by num_1) as result
```

Comment: @NorahJones . . . The results don't make sense to me and your first comment does nothing to make it clearer.  You should edit the *question* with a clear explanation.  Your explanation of "highest value" makes no reference to the "level" columns, but they seem important to your logic.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I have created a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731107/results-per-row-based-on-partitioned-columns, would you mind taking a look?

Comment: I really tried to get the logic - I failed - I doubt anyone can get this. you need provide more details and show different cases with detailed explanation

Comment: what also can help is if you provide real life example of what you are trying to implement - otherwise it is too abstract

Answer (score 0):

The following simple logic returns the values you specify.  It is not clear if this is what you actually intend:

```
select (case when not level_2 then num_3
             else num_2
        end)
```

My best guess is that a relatively simple `case` expression is what you need.  I am just unclear on what you really need.

Comment: @NorahJones . . . This question has been closed.  You might want to ask a *new* question, focusing on the explanation your provided (with sample data and desired results).

Comment: I've created a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731107/results-per-row-based-on-partitioned-columns